# How to use the Kendo DataSource class to access a local json file

Tags: kendo-ui

Our project uses the SPA's "Hot Towel" template, which includes the Durandal framework.

We're also using Telrik's Kendo UI, and I'm having trouble using the DataSource widget to simply read in a local json formatted file from my project folder.

I'd like to read a test data file from either my "app\app_data\" folder to my "app\viewmodels" folder.

Of course if I hard code my data into the js function it works fine. Like this for example:

```
var ds2 = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        data:
            [{  data here" }];
           });
```

ds.read()

However, trying to read from local project folder will not work. I'd like to simply mockup some test data while developing.
Your advice would be appreciated.

```
var ds = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        transport: {
            **read**: {
                url: "PositionsTestData.json",    // "../app/app_data/PositionsTestData.json",
                dataType: "json"
            }
        }
    });
    ds.read();          // in console, ds.data is showing 0 records.
```

I'm also trying a std jquery ajax get:

var jq = $.ajax({
            url: "app/viewmodels/PositionsTestData.json",
            type: "get",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: 'application/json'
        });

I'm seeing 404 NOT FOUND in Chrome inspector tool, under Network tab.

thank you.
Bob

Comment: Open your browser's development tools, and check out the network traffic.  See if the request for PositionsTestData.json is actually happening, and if it is, what is the return code ?  200, awesome, we'll examine the dataSource, 400+ we've got problems.

Comment: 404 not found error. I've also edited my original post to show the updated ajax call I'm trying via jquery...

Comment: also tried:   var jq1 = $.getJSON("App/App_Data/PositionsTestData.json");

Comment: Don't you guys think that it would be a major security flaw if you could load arbitrary files from a client computer?  Copy the json data into a separate .js file and be done with it.

Comment: I guess you need to figure out where the json file is, then use that as the url.  As long as the website, and the json file are on the same domain, you shouldn't have any cross-domain issues. Just need the right url.